# Constructor with string parameter and identical overload with object parameter

Tags: c#, overloading, constructor-overloading

My class currently has two constructors, which are overloads:

```
public CustomRangeValidationAttribute(string value) {}
```

and

```
public CustomRangeValidationAttribute(object value) {}
```

this appears to be working correctly: When I call the method using a `string` the first constructor is called, when I use different values, for example an `integer` or `boolean`, the second constructor is called.

I assume there is a rule to force specific type matches into the more specific overload, preventing

```
var c = new CustomRangeValidationAttrubute("test");
```

from calling the object-overload.

Is this "safe code", or should (or can) the code be improved? I have a nagging feeling this is not the best practice.

Comment: Depends, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to be sure there are absolutely no risks of the wrong constructor getting called. And if that's not the case, it still feels like a bad practice somehow.

Comment: If the `object` based method will do something *fundamentally different/wrong* if it happens to be called with a `string`, that's probably a *logical error* in creating overloads in the first place, but nothing to do with the calling code.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the overload will be selected at compile time so if you have an object reference which is actually a string, the 2nd overload will be called (unless you cast the object to a string).

Comment: In the latter overload, consider checking whether the parameter is a string - and if it is, cast to string and call the first overload.

Comment: @mjwills - difficult to do with constructors, since you can't run logic before chaining (in C#)

Comment: Ah, good point @Damien_The_Unbeliever. You'd need to extract the `string` constructor into a separate method and then call **that** method from the `object` constructor.

Comment: Personally, I'd be really hesitant to do this;  I'd add strongly-typed constructor overloads for each type that I need as they pop up if I really had to.  It's extremely unclear to anyone who's using this what this is expecting as that parameter, and it's leaving itself open to weird behaviour as you have no idea what people *might* pass into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two overloads which only vary in the reference types and there's a hierarchical relationship between the reference types, such that one may be cast to the other.

In such a circumstance, you really ought to make sure that the code behaves the same *logically* when the broader overload is selected but the reference turns out to be of the more derived type<sup>1,2</sup>. *That* is where to focus your attention. Of course, if you can stick by this rule, often it'll turn out that the more derived overload isn't required and can just be special-cased *within* the broader method.

---

<sup>1</sup>Especially because, as vc74 points out in a comment, overload resolution (generally, ignoring `dynamic`) is done at compile time based on compile-time types<sup>3</sup>.

<sup>2</sup>And this fits the same broad principal for overloads. Don't have overloads where *which one is selected* leads to logically different results. If you're exhibiting different behaviours, don't give them the same name (for constructors, that may mean splitting into two separate classes, possibly with a shared base class, if that's what you intend to do)

<sup>3</sup>I appreciate that this is for an attribute and so you're expecting only compile-time to be relevant, but I'd still hew to the general principal here, where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Once there is overload with signature of more derived type the compiler will always choose most concrete type you provide.

That being said, unless someone does `new CustomRangeValidationAttrubute((object)"test")` if you pass string to `CustomRangeValidationAttrubute` always constructor with `string` in it's parameter will be chosen.

About if this is bad practice, I can't tell for sure if I don't see your specific use case, just keep in mind every value type you pass to `new CustomRangeValidationAttrubute(object)` will be boxed and this is bad as it puts pressure to the GC and whats more you will loose type safety.

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this code was by moving the overloads to a new abstract class with separate methods instead of the the original constructors:

```
public CustomRangeValidationStringAttribute(string value) {}

public CustomRangeValidationGenericAttribute(object value) {}
```

In the two classes inheriting from this new base class each use their own method, creating two different attributes to choose from, [CustomRangeValidationString] and [CustomRangeValidationGeneric].

Answer (score -1):

You could use a generic class.

[See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)

```
class YourClass<T> 
{
    public YourClass(T value){}
}
```

Comment: Thought I didn't state it explicitly, my class is an attribute, inheriting from RemoteAttribute and unfortunately generics are not allowed in attribute classes.